# git svn dcommit always fails with "Cannot dcommit with a dirty index."

Tags: git, git-svn

```
$ git --version
git version 1.7.0.3
```

I clone an SVN repository, and make a commit:

```
$ git svn clone --stdlayout http://svn/example/project
$ echo test >> blah.txt
$ git commit -m "Something"
```

When I try and `dcommit` back to the SVN, I get the following error:

```
$ git svn dcommit
Cannot dcommit with a dirty index.  Commit your changes first, or stash them with `git stash'.
 at .../git/1.7.0.3/.../libexec/git-core/git-svn line 497
```

..despite the branch being seemingly clean:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

The only place I can see the non-existent "unstaged changes" is in `gitk`, where it says "Local uncommitted changes, not checked in to index"

Running `git stash` allows the `dcommit` to work for some reason:

```
$ git stash
No local changes to save
$ git svn dcommit
Committing to http://svn/example/project ...
        M       blah.txt
Committed r65913
        M       blah.txt
r65913 = a5547d761108d233211f115429e23ddca73bf4bc (refs/remotes/trunk)
No changes between current HEAD and refs/remotes/trunk
Resetting to the latest refs/remotes/trunk
```

I have an alias to run `git stash; git svn dcommit; git stash apply` - but this is not the best workaround, as it causes merge errors when using actually using the stash

Comment: I'm encountering the same thing, 3 years later.  Unfortunately, it's gotten worse.  git stash does NOT allow me to dcommit.

Comment: % git svn dcommit
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': both revision and filename
Use '--' to separate filenames from revisions
Cannot dcommit with a dirty index.  Commit your changes first, or stash them with `git stash'.
 at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 760

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I was writing the question, I found the following commit:

http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/commitdiff/181264ad590ffef9d956fdd023369869c2d0a55f

> The dcommit command fails if an
>   otherwise unmodified file has been
>   touched in the working directory:
>
> ```
> Cannot dcommit with a dirty index.  Commit your changes
> first, or stash them with `git stash'.
> ```
>
> This happens because "git diff-index"
>   reports a difference between the index
>   and the filesystem:
>
> ```
> :100644 100644 d00491...... 000000...... M      file
> ```
>
> The fix is to run "git update-index
>   --refresh" before "git diff-index" as is done in git-rebase and
>   git-rebase--interactive before "git
>   diff-files".
>
> This changes dcommit to display a list
>   of modified files before exiting.
>
> Also add a similar test case for "git
>   svn rebase".

Can't decipher from the git log what version the change is in, but it looks like the change should be in the version after `1.7.2.2`

**Edit:** As of Nov 19, 2011, the commit is still only in the master branch:

```
$ git branch --contains 181264ad590ffef9d956fdd023369869c2d0a55f
* master
```

**Edit2:** This change is now in git 1.7.3 onwards

```
> git tag --contains 181264ad590ffef9d956fdd023369869c2d0a55f | sort -V
v1.7.3
[...]
```

Comment: git update-index --refresh doesn't help me, and I'm using git 1.7.9.

Answer (score 0):

I received similar error when I tried to execute `git svn dcommit`.

I tried to commit from non-root git folder (which contains `.git`-subfolder) and with changes in SVN repo which I have not retrieved yet to git via `git svn rebase`.